# SQL Alphabet reference for rows in query

Tags: sql

I am using a query, to print 'reference' alphabet. It works fine for single table, but prints `NULL` when I do a join

```
SELECT
   Letters = Char(64 + T.student_id),
   T.Student_name
   FROM
   dbo.Students T
Inner join dbo.date_of_birth dob ON T.student_id = dob.student_id
```

Comment: What does you data look like?  Are there runs in the date_of_birth table that match?

Comment: I think you are crossing the 255 limit. You should be using CHAR() for values from 0 to 255.

Comment: That is non-standard SQL. Which DBMS are you using?

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you are trying to add a prefix of "64" on the student id, maybe you could use the following SQL statements

IF student_id is a character data type (ex. VARCHAR):

```
SELECT Letters = '64' + T.student_id,
       T.Student_name
  FROM dbo.Students T
 INNER JOIN dbo.date_of_birth dob
    ON T.student_id = dob.student_id
```

IF student_id is a numeric  data type (ex. INT):

```
SELECT Letters = '64' + CAST(T.student_id AS VARCHAR),
       T.Student_name
  FROM dbo.Students T
 INNER JOIN dbo.date_of_birth dob
    ON T.student_id = dob.student_id
```